# Excel: How to return comment as a cell from a conditional

Tags: excel, comments

How to return comment as a cell from a conditional.

Example:

```
=if(a1=0;insert comment on cell)
```

insert comment and show comment

Comment: You can't do that with a worksheet function.  You could do it with a VBA macro.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221696(v=office.11).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could not find any way with default worksheet functions, so you might have to declare your own function for this - like this:

```
Public Function GetComment(rng As Range) as String
  GetComment = rng.NoteText
 'also possible
 'GetComment = rng.Comment.Text
End Function
```

Save this function into a Module, so it is accessible as a worksheetfunction.

then use `=if(a1=0;GetComment(A1))` to return the comment.

*edit:*

Because I might have misunderstood a bit - here is a verison, which adds a comment to the caller-cell, sets its content to the given comment and makes the comment visible.

```
Public Function AddCmt(strComment As String) As String
  Dim rngCaller As Range
  If TypeName(Application.Caller) Like "Range" Then
    Set rngCaller = Application.Caller
    With rngCaller
      If .Comment Is Nothing Then
        .AddComment (strComment)
      Else
        .Comment.Text strComment
      End If
      .Comment.Visible = True
    End With
    'set caller-cell content to given comment
    AddCmt= strComment
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: You are correct, you can only edit comments programmatically via VBA.